# Исключения,python

Tags: python

```
def rec(n):
    if n < 10: 
       return n 
    else: 
       return n % 10 + rec(n / 10) 

n = int(input("n = "))
print("rec(%d) = %d" % (n, rec(n)))

try:
    n = int(n) 
 except ValueError:
    print("Ошибка ввода!")
```

Написал рекурсию, которая считает сумму цифр числа. Не знаю куда вставить конструкцию `try`,чтоб программа нормально работала. Куда не впишу, ошибку выдает. Не очень еще разобрался с этими исключениями.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блоком `try` следует окружать то место, где ошибка возникает:

```
try:
    n = int(input("n = "))
except ValueError:
    print("Ошибка ввода!")
else:
    print("rec(%d) = %d" % (n, rec(n)))
```